# What sentence is hidden here?

Tags: cipher, visual, knowledge

The title says it all, try and find it!

[image]

Not sure about the tags, don't really want to spoil it too much...

I will add hints if required :)

P.S. Gray is just a frame

Comment: Hold back with hints, you don't want to spoil it. Wait at least until you're asked for one, or for 2 - 3 days of non-action. If you think one can get to a unambiguous answer with the information given, just wait. If not, ensure that the needed information is in the puzzle right from the start - it would be *essential* not a hint. See also [here](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5005/when-should-i-add-hints-to-my-puzzle) and [here](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5121/when-can-i-ask-for-a-hint?s=1|0.8084)

Comment: By the way - can someone suggest a decent app/program/website which would be good for manipulating this grid. I want to play around with it, like flipping rows/columns around..

Comment: @BmyGuest thanks! I will add hints later then :)

Comment: @QuestionAsker Do Google Sheets work for you?  See this [meta-thread](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/5035/5840)

Comment: @QuestionAsker flipping rows/columns around would be unnecessary :)

Comment: Hmm, rotating the image 90 degrees I have the feeling I could *nearly* read the white as text. But just quite... The last bit would be N 11 ??

Comment: @BmyGuest Don't view the image as a whole, view it as a grid of black and white squares. Look for a "pattern" :)

Comment: @GintasK: Take BmyGuest's first comment to heart.  People are using the comments to collaborate on solving, not to be pointed in the right direction at every step.

Comment: Noticed rows 3, 6, 9, 12, 15 and 18 are identical. So are the column pairs (1,2), (7,8), (13, 14).

Comment: Ok people, no more hints or pointings for now, good luck!

Comment: If you look at the repeating patterns, you can think of the grid as 18 cells, 3 high by 6 wide each.  Here's what it looks like if you remove the common squares from each: http://i.imgur.com/Xe7WBcU.png (forgive the rough editing).  Notably it leaves you with 8 "unique" squares per cell, which could suggest a binary encoding, but I can't find a way to map it to ASCII that makes sense.

Comment: Noticed: Counting the "area" of white spots gives value between 2 and 26. Nothing found yet, though.

Comment: @MarkPeters What does a straight-forward binary converstion of the squares give? Anyone who wants can join me [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZqvLLlwB2STxPoWUIFQqztP9L69kmvOyVwsrpPhIzLM/edit?usp=sharing) for some comunity puzzling...

Comment: @BmyGuest: Depends which square represents which binary digit.  If you take the top-left to be the most significant and descend left-to-right, you get a whole bunch of unprintable control characters (e.g. 0x01), assuming ASCII.  If not ASCII, then you get a whole bunch of values which would be outside of the logical range of a simple alphabet encoding (~1-26).  It's hard to see how any reading of binary would have values in the range of an english sentence.

Comment: Here's the grid broken into 3x6 cells without removing anything, if it's helpful: http://i.imgur.com/XWa2TGL.png.

Comment: Hmm, if the borders are just to separate the junks, then we likely need only the information in the 2x5 sections of each tile...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42884/discussion-between-bmyguest-and-mark-peters).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's braille numbers!

> #76#78#76 
>        #44#32#86
>        #71#39#70
>        #32#83#69
>        #86#81#78
>        #76#33#33

that's ASCII (or unicode)

> `LNL, VG'F SEVQNL!!`

rot13

> YAY, IT'S FRIDAY!!

the comment that the rows and columns should not be rearranged helped a lot.